# How to stop run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)

Tags: shell, cron

I create file named `database_backup.sh` and put it in `/etc/cron.daily/`. Crontab expression is:

```
30 04 * * * /etc/cron.daily/database_backup.sh
```

However, it runs twice every day,  I find log like this:

```
May 18 03:26:01 10-10-46-208 run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[8478]: starting database_backup.sh
May 18 04:30:01 10-10-46-208 CROND[13673]: (root) CMD (/etc/cron.daily/database_backup.sh)

May 19 03:39:01 10-10-46-208 run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[29669]: starting database_backup.sh
May 19 04:30:01 10-10-46-208 CROND[2530]: (root) CMD (/etc/cron.daily/database_backup.sh)

May 20 03:44:01 10-10-46-208 run-parts(/etc/cron.daily)[20184]: starting database_backup.sh
May 20 04:30:01 10-10-46-208 CROND[23886]: (root) CMD (/etc/cron.daily/database_backup.sh)
```

My question is: how to stop run-parts let it run only at 4:30?

Answer (score 1):

I think generally it is not a good idea to store your shell scripts in the `cron.d` folder, however, Linux lets you put anything nearly everywhere...

The main problem here is that the default `run-parts` directive runs every scripts under the cron.d folder, then your cron command runs it again.

- More info about `run-parts` can be found **[here](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man8/run-parts.8.html)**.

So you can either:

- take out the run-parts from your crontab
- or put your script under `/usr/bin/local` or some other preferred location, and change your crontab accordingly.